# Sanddisk drive write protected

Tags: usb, filesystem, error-handling, troubleshooting

My sanddisk usb write protected
i tried

```
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdc1 /mnt
mount: block device /dev/sdc1 is write-protected, mounting read-only

# sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system
```

and

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb1
```

and i tried fsck command also

```
Start cluster field in VFAT long filename slot is not 0 (but 0xdb2c).
1: Fix.
2: Leave it.
? 1
Unfinished long file name "쀸雉梆Ồ궏꾧썏ᔘ钾꾲彪Ꮦ".
  (Start may have been overwritten by ─Σæ#)
1: Delete LFN
2: Leave it as it is.
3: Fix numbering (truncates long name and attaches it to short name ─Σæ#)
? 1
Reserved field in VFAT long filename slot is not 0 (but 0xdc).
1: Fix.
2: Leave it.
? 1
Start cluster field in VFAT long filename slot is not 0 (but 0xdb2c).
1: Fix.
2: Leave it.
? 1
Unfinished long file name "쀸雉梆Ồ궏꾧썏ᔘ钾꾲彪Ꮦ".
  (Start may have been overwritten by ─Σæ#)
1: Delete LFN
2: Leave it as it is.
3: Fix numbering (truncates long name and attaches it to short name ─Σæ#)
? 1
Reserved field in VFAT long filename slot is not 0 (but 0xdc).
1: Fix.
2: Leave it.
? 1
Start cluster field in VFAT long filename slot is not 0 (but 0xdb2c).
1: Fix.
2: Leave it.
? 1
Unfinished long file name "쀸雉梆Ồ궏꾧썏ᔘ钾꾲彪Ꮦ".
  (Start may have been overwritten by ─Σæ#)
1: Delete LFN
2: Leave it as it is.
3: Fix numbering (truncates long name and attaches it to short name ─Σæ#)
? 1
/SEKAHR2/SEKHAR/Sekhar/English/Spoken English/Vasundra/All/AB
  Has a large number of bad entries. (948/1008)
Drop directory ? (y/n) 
1
Invalid input.
Drop directory ? (y/n) 1
Invalid input.
Drop directory ? (y/n) 1
Invalid input.
Drop directory ? (y/n) y
1


Read 32 bytes at 283836416:Input/output error
```

and

```
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
You will not be able to write the partition table.

Command (m for help): o
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x8c87117f.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-30965759, default 2048): 
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-30965759, default 30965759): 
Using default value 30965759

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list codes): c
Changed system type of partition 1 to c (W95 FAT32 (LBA))

Command (m for help): w
fdisk: unable to write /dev/sdb: Bad file descriptor
```

but iam unable to formatting it is there any solution for this?

Comment: ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb
has been opened read-only.
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb
has been opened read-only.
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sdb will be destroyed and all data on
this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? y
Error: Can't write to /dev/sdb, because it is opened read-only.           
Ignore/Cancel? I

Comment: unmount the drive and remount it R/W

Comment: ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only

Comment: that ^^ what he said and check for a hardware switch. That one might have a slider to put it in read only mode.

Comment: there is no hardware switch

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `mount` to it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your usb drive may have bad blocks, so many bad blocks that the kernel is forcing a read-only mount. To check whether this is true, check the kernel message buffer with `sudo dmesg` and look for signs such as `Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupted. Please run fsck` or `Input/Output error`, and most importantly, `Filesystem has been set read-only`. If this is the case, it may be likely that there is not save (i.e. your drive is dying), however you could try the below to squeeze some life back out of it (it may not work though).

I had this problem once with a dying SD card of mine. You could try creating an entirely new partition table (not just reformat) and then reformat.

To create an entirely new partition table (this will destroy all data on the drive), run `fdisk /dev/path/to/device` (you want the device itself and not an individual partition -- in your case it would look something like like `fdisk /dev/sdc` and NOT `/dev/sdc1`).

At the fdisk prompt,

- type `o` for new partition table, then
- `n` for new partition (and accept all the defaults),
- `t` then `c` to change partition type to one suitable for a FAT filesystem
- then `w` to write changes to disk

At this point you should have a device with a new partition (something like `/dev/sdc1`: you can check with `lsblk`. Try and format that partition. Best of luck.

Comment: its not working i tried that also see the output in my question

Comment: @ashok "`Bad file descriptor`" If the kernel can't get it right than I'd give up on the drive... :(

Comment: I have a had this happen many times with SD cards over the years.   They all died.  I couldn't even restore them using the official Microsoft Windows SandDisk software.  That software gave me similar errors, and both OS's told me there was very little space on thee SD cards.